# Dynamic global configuration for toastr

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

Am using `ngx-toastr` lib for couple of notifications and different use cases. All works fine.

The only point am still struggling with, is a **dynamic** global configuration. I mean the one used in `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
   ...
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   ToastrModule.forRoot({
      maxOpened: 1,
      ...
   }),
   ....
]
```

I would like to pass the configuration object dynamically using a property in env file.
I don't want to use any custom component for this such as:

```
imports: [
  ...
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ToastrModule.forRoot({
      toastComponent: MyToastRCustomComponent
  }),
  ....
```

]

I'm thinking about creating a service for this.. any other hint or idea which could be more suitable?